# Can't draw a good flow chart with item list

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, flow-charts

I need to draw a flow chart with items in bullet points. I tried drawing using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    % Place nodes

      \node  [block] (init)
      {
      {dataset 
      \begin{itemize}
       \item Boundary dataset
       \item Emission dataset
      \end{itemize}}
      }

    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Run Model  WRF-Chem};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {Model Result \item PM and ozone \item fire and nofire values};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate] (evaluation) {Result Validation \item OM and ozone from instrument  \item For AOD modis datas};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (evaluation);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I also tried:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
\begin{itemize}

    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Data collection \item Boundary dataset  \item Emission dataset};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Run Model \item WRF-Chem};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {Model Result \item PM and ozone \item fire and nofire values};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate] (evaluation) {Result Validation \item OM and ozone from instrument  \item For AOD modis datas};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (evaluation);

\end{itemize}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the figure  comes like the following:

[image]

How can I organize the bullets so that it comes in the exact place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not complete, I've invented the definition of `block` and `line`.

You forgot `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` in two nodes.

After these two corrections, it works perfectly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        draw, 
        rounded corners,
        text width=12em,
        text centered,
        minimum height=20ex,
        fill=cyan!70!white
    },
    line/.style={
        draw, 
        -Stealth
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
      \node  [block] (init)
      {
      {dataset 
      \begin{itemize}
       \item Boundary dataset
       \item Emission dataset
      \end{itemize}}
      };
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Run Model  WRF-Chem};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {Model Result \begin{itemize}
    \item PM and ozone 
    \item fire and nofire values
    \end{itemize}};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate] (evaluation) {Result Validation \begin{itemize}
    \item OM and ozone from instrument  
    \item For AOD modis datas
    \end{itemize}};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (evaluation);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

mostly off-topic, since cause of your problem is already explained in  [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482017/cant-draw-a-good-flow-chart-with-item-list/482218#482218) answer.

with using `tikz` libraries `arrows.meta` (for arrows), `chains` (for link nodes in chain and conect them by use of its macro `join) and`positioning`(to determine distance between nodes) , and the package`enumitem` (for lists in nodes) ypu can redesign your flowchart in the following look-out:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3ex,
  start chain = going below,
every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
                     text width=11em, minimum height=12ex,
                     align=center,
                     on chain, join=by -Stealth}
                        ]
\setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,
                    leftmargin=*}
%
\node   {dataset
        \begin{itemize}
   \item Boundary dataset
   \item Emission dataset
    \end{itemize}};
\node   {Run Model  WRF-Chem};
\node   {Model Result
        \begin{itemize}
   \item PM and ozone
   \item fire and nofire values
        \end{itemize}};
\node   {Result Validation
        \begin{itemize}
   \item OM and ozone from instrument
   \item For AOD modis datas
        \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```